# Azure pipeline not able to deploy .ispac in file share folder on Azure storage account

Tags: azure-devops, ssis, azure-pipelines, azure-file-share

The issue is the pipeline doesn't copy the ispac file on File Share of the Storage account.

Using 'Deploy SSIS' task, I'm able to copy .dtsx and .dtsConfig files inside the File Share [example image task Deploy SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxOxR.png)

this is possible because inside the Deployment folder (in the 'bin' ones) there is the SSISDeploymentManifest file that contains this kind of code (maybe there's a way to include the .ispac inside it(?))

`<?xml version="1.0"?> <DTSDeploymentManifest GeneratedBy="" GeneratedFromProjectName="AzurePipelineDeploy" GeneratedDate="2024-01-31T09:41:37.7719773+01:00" AllowConfigurationChanges="true"> <Package>Package.dtsx</Package> <ConfigurationFile>Config.dtsConfig</ConfigurationFile> </DTSDeploymentManifest>`

What I need is to copy also the .ispac file that I have inside the Development folder (in the 'bin' ones).

If I try to do that duplicating the task and changing the source path, I get this error **PipelineDevOps\AzurePipelineDeploy\bin\Development\AzurePipelineDeploy.ispac isn't a valid file which ends with SSISDeploymentManifest**

Also if I copy the .ispac inside the Deployment folder, the pipeline ignores the ispac file and upload only .dtsx and .dtsConfig

I've tried also with Azure CLI task [example image task Azure CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZiZG.png) but it gives me this error **The term 'PipelineDevOps/AzurePipelineDeploy/bin/Development' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.**

Answer (score 0):

Per the requirement to copy file from agent path onto Azure Storage Account file share, you may test with the `azcopy` command, which is already installed on Microsoft-hosted agents. See [Transfer data with AzCopy and file storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files) for more information.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    tree PipelineDevOps/AzurePipelineDeploy/bin/Development
    azcopy --version
    echo "1. List file share:"
    azcopy list "https://$(Storageaccount).file.core.windows.net$(SASToken)"
    echo "2. Copy files to file share:"
    azcopy copy 'PipelineDevOps/AzurePipelineDeploy/bin/Development/' "https://$(Storageaccount).file.core.windows.net/$(FileShareName)$(SASToken)" --recursive
```